# Cannot install python packages thorugh PyPi in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, pip, pypi, databricks

I want to call a webservice from a Databricks Notebook through Python. The needed library for this seems to be http.client.

I have already found a code snippet to test this but when i try to execute it i get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named http.client

This is correct cause i have no module installed yet.

In the next step i go to a folder within my Databricks, select Import -> Import Notebooks dialog click on `(To import a library, such as a jar or egg, click here)` -> Select in the `Language` DropDown `Upload Python Egg or PyPI -> in pyPI name type`http.client` and click on Install Library.

Then i select `Attach automatically to all clusters`.

I receive the following error:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation failed with message:
>   Collecting http.client Collecting http.client Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement http.client (from versions: ) No
>   matching distribution found for http.client You are using pip version
>   9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. Could not find
>   a version that satisfies the requirement http.client (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for http.client You are using pip
>   version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available. You should consider
>   upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? [**`http.client`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) is part of Python 3

Comment: Python Version is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you import httplib, it must resolve the issue

Comment: Python Version is 2